# How to check whether `malloc.h` is available in C?

Tags: c, linux, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

`malloc.h` is a non-standard C header that declares extensions to the C standard library related to memory management. It is available on Linux.

I want my program to compile on many platforms but only use `malloc.h` functionality when it is available.

How can I check during compile time (via macros) whether the `malloc.h` library is available for my C program?

Edit: a solution could also go indirectly, such as checking the operating system, or anything else.

Comment: Frame challenge: if your program can accommodate systems that do not provide any of the non-standard features declared in `malloc.h`, then why do you need `malloc.h` *anywhere*?  Note well that you don't need it for `malloc` / `calloc` / `realloc`, which are declared in `stdlib.h` in any C library that conforms to *any* published version of the C language specifications.

Answer (score 3):

You generate (autoconf, shell script creates a small c program etc) a header file, say, config.h, that only includes the header if is available.  Optionally define a constant if you don't want to rely on what malloc.h defines:

```
#include <malloc.h>
#define MALLOC_H_FOUND 1
```

Then you code you include this header file and only perform actions based on a symbol found in malloc.h or the constant you defined above:

```
#include "config.h"

#ifdef _MALLOC_H // or MALLOC_H_FOUND
  // use malloc.c specific features
#else
 // fallback
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

> via macros

It's not possible to check for header existence "via macros".

Typically, create a small valid program with `#include <malloc.h>` and try to compile that program. If the compilation is successful, means the header is available. Build systems are tools created exactly for that goal of automating such tasks, there are for example: `CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE()` in cmake, `AC_CHECK_HEADER()` in autoconf, `conf.CheckCHeader` in scons, `cc.has_header` in meson, etc.

Note: there is a gcc extension `__has_include` https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/_005f_005fhas_005finclude.html that is going into C23 https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/23 . If you aim only for gcc or only for C23, you can use `#if __has_include(<malloc.h>)`.

Comment: I appreciate your note.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to try to compile a program that includes malloc.h, and then check the return code from the compiler. If the compiler returns an error, then malloc.h is not available.

Here's a simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main() {
  printf("Hello, world!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

If you try to compile this program on a system that doesn't have malloc.h, you'll get an error like this:

> gcc test.c
> test.c:2:18: fatal error: malloc.h: No such file or directory
> #include <malloc.h>
> ^
> compilation terminated.

If malloc.h is available, the program will compile without errors